# How to get values which do not exist in databse by comparing with the list values in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am having a spring boot application which reads values from the Microsoft access file and then checks if the value exists in the database then gets updated or else inserted as the new record however I'm only getting these values present in the database and I'm not able to get the values which are missing from the database I don't know where I'm doing it wrong but here is the code I have

Model Class

```
 @Data
    @Entity
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "tbl_tests")
    public class Test {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Long id;
        private String customId;
        private String testTypeId;
        private LocalDateTime testDate;
        private LocalDateTime resultDate;
        private Float resultNumeric;
    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {
    
  @Query(value = "select t from Test t where t.customId =:customId and t.testDate =:testDate and t.testTypeId =:testType")
  Test findByTestParams(String customId, LocalDateTime testDate, String testType);
  
}
```

service class

```
@Service
public class TestProcessingService {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepository;
    
    @Async
    public void processData(Path filepath) throws IOException, SQLException {
    
    List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(filepath.toString())).getTable("tblTests");
    
    for(Row row : table) {
            
    Test dbData = testRepository.findByTestParams(row.get("CustomID"), (LocalDateTime) row.get("TestDate"), (String) row.get("TestTypeID"));
   
    if(dbData == null) {
            
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setCustomId(row.get("CustomID"));
    test.setTestTypeId((String) row.get("TestTypeID"));
    test.setTestDate((LocalDateTime) row.get("TestDate"));
    test.setResultNumeric((Float) row.get("ResultNumeric"));
    testList.add(test);
          
    } else {
        
     dbData.setCustomId(row.get("CustomID"));
     dbData.setTestTypeId((String) row.get("TestTypeID"));
     dbData.setTestDate((LocalDateTime) row.get("TestDate"));
     dbData.setResultNumeric((Float) row.get("ResultNumeric"));
     testList.add(dbData); 
    
    }
    }
    testRepository.saveAll(testList);
    
}
}
```

Api Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data_api")
public class UploadApi {
    
    @Autowired
    private DataUploadService dataUploadService;

    @PostMapping("/upload_file")
    protected UploadResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException,SQLException {
    return dataUploadService.uploadFile(file);
    }
    
}
```

I'm not able to get the null values so that I can insert them as a new record, I'm only getting the values that are present inside the database. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Also a point to note is that some customId keeps reapeating due to different test dates.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not able to get the null values"? Does the universe stop before returning a value? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Also you shouldn't need the select and the if condition. Just creating the entity instances and persisting them should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not getting any exception and also the universe does not stop the only thing I'm confused is that, I'm able to get the values present in database and I'm not able to get the values which are missing or not present in the database therefore I'm not in position to get to this part of an if statement, "if(dbData == null) { do something ...}" @JensSchauder

Comment: how can I create the entity instances and persisting them, please a little example @JensSchauder

Comment: What does your application do in the cases where it should go into the `dbDatat == null` branch?

Comment: remove the content of your for loop except the content of the if block.

Comment: dbData == null means that data is not present in database so I have to insert it as a new record @JensSchauder

Comment: removing the content of for loop it will be impossible to check or compare the values fetched from the Access file with that from the database or is there any simplest way to do it @JensSchauder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253538/discussion-between-jens-schauder-and-janeth-jackson).